# What is the meaning of the word “Jovie”?

Tags: meaning

For a non english speaker what is Jovie ?

I’ve looked for the definitions at Google images, which provides some various conotations [Google Images Search for Jovie](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=jovie&client=safari&rls=en&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=MgC0U_6TFqT_ywOeyIF4&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_)

Comment: It looks like a name, and possibly a brand name. I've never heard the word before, but from those images it looks like there are multiple meanings.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that you're asking for a translation of this word, as a) you ask for its meaning 'for a non english speaker' and b) it does not appear to be an English word. If I'm wrong then please correct me, but otherwise this question would be off-topic.

Comment: 568ml yes I’m asking for the translation. If that’s an off-topic then please close this question. I would appreciate a reference to where I should be looking for a translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jovie does not have an exact definition in the English language; it is a name.

**Jovie** is gaining prominence as a name for a girl. According to [dubious](http://www.babynamewizard.com/baby-name/girl/jovie) [internet](http://www.babynames.com/name/Jovie) [sources](http://nameberry.com/babyname/Jovie), it

> is an American take on "happy", "joyous", or "jovial".

[As anyone can tell you](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qRtyNkpS1i4), American names don't have meaning.

Also, [Jovie](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0011306/) was the name of a character in Elf (2003), played by Zooey Deschanel. This probably wasn't the origin of the name, but it no doubt played a part in the rise in popularity of the name.

You may have also misread or confused this with a reference to [Bon Jovi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon_Jovi) (born John Francis Bongiovi, Jr.).